# why this python function skips index 1 to 3 without iterating index 2 when running in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I wrote a function in order to remove parts that duplicates in two strings. I first transform string into list and iterate through the two list to find if characters on the same position are the same. The problem is when iterating,
the code skips index 2. (ex:list="index",the iterator jump to 'd' after iterating 'i').

I've tried to use "replace" method to do string operation but I did not get the result I want. "Replace" method removed parts that I want.

```
def popp(s,t): 
    s_lis=list(s)
    t_lis=list(t)
    ind=0
    for i,j in zip(s_lis,t_lis):
        if i==j:
            s_lis.pop(ind)
            t_lis.pop(ind)
        else:ind+=1        
    return s_lis,t_lis

# test the code
print(popp('hackerhappy','hackerrank'))
```

```
expected result: ['h','p','p','y'] ['r','n','k']
actual result: ['k', 'r', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'y'], ['k', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'k']
```

Comment: You can use zip_longest to achieve this. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, you should use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) which makes a zip out of the longest subsequence.  You are using `zip` which makes a zip out of the shortest subsequence which is what you don't want.
So in our case, it will be

```
print(list(zip_longest(s_lis, t_lis)))
#[('h', 'h'), ('a', 'a'), ('c', 'c'), ('k', 'k'), ('e', 'e'), 
#('r', 'r'), ('h', 'r'), ('a', 'a'), ('p', 'n'), ('p', 'k'), ('y', None)]
```

Then you should use another list to append the non-common characters rather then operating on the same list you are iterating on via `s_lis.pop(idx)`
So if the characters in the tuple do not match, append them if they are not None

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def popp(s,t):
    s_lis = list(s)
    t_lis = list(t)
    s_res = []
    t_res = []
    #Use zip_longest to zip the two lists
    for i, j in zip_longest(s_lis, t_lis):
        #If the characters do not match, and they are not None, append them 
        #to the list
        if i != j:
            if i!=None:
                s_res.append(i)
            if j!=None:
                t_res.append(j)
    return s_res, t_res
```

The output will look like:

```
print(popp('hackerhappy','hackerrank'))
#(['h', 'p', 'p', 'y'], ['r', 'n', 'k'])
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you meaning that I should create other lists once I want to extract sth from a list?

Comment: Yes, you should never modify the list using pop like you were doing and were already iterating on.

Answer (score 0):

**You could modify your code slightly**

```
def popp(s, t):
    s_lis = list(s)
    t_lis = list(t)
    s_res = []
    t_res = []

    # match each character. Stops once the
    # shortest list ends
    for i, j in zip(s_lis, t_lis):
        if i != j:
            s_res.append(i)
            t_res.append(j)

    # if s is longer, take rest of the string and
    # add it to residual
    if len(s) > len(t):
        for x in s_lis[len(t):]:
            s_res.append(x)

    if len(t) > len(s):
        for x in t_lis[len(s):]:
            t_res.append(x)

    print(s_res)
    print(t_res)

popp('hackerhappy','hackerrank')
```